# How do I create JTabbedPane tabs with multiple line title

Tags: jtabbedpane

I would like to have the tab on a JTabbedPane be multiple lines. I have tried adding newline character, but the title remains as one line. Is there a way I can break the title up to be display as a multi line title? The development environment is Java 1.7 using NetBeans IDE 8.0

Comment: Have you tried using html?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned in the post, that this is Java environment. I updated the post to reflect the environment.

Comment: Please read the link in my first post. You will see that you can embed html in java code.